# When is the median closest nearest-neighbor distance larger than the mean closest nearest-neighbor distance?

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Consider a random Poisson process in an $d$-dimensional cube of arbitrary size (alternatively, consider an arbitrarily large $(d-1)$-dimensional sphere in an $d$-dimensional space).  If we have a random Poisson process that randomly and uniformly distributes points in the $d$-dimensional space $S$ internal to the $d$-cube or $(d-1)$-dimensional sphere until a density $\rho = \frac{n}{Vol(S)}$ is achieved:

Under what conditions is the median point-to-point closest nearest-neighbor distance larger than the mean point-to-point closest nearest-neighbor distance? Is there a closed-form analytic expression for the median closest nearest-neighbor distance as a function of $d$ and $n$?

The best treatment I've seen for calculating the probability distribution for nearest-neighbor distances is from Chandrasekhar's "Stochastic Problems in Physics and Astronomy" Rev. Mod. Phys. 15, 1–89 (1943): http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v15/i1/p1_1 (sorry for the paywall), but this paper does not tackle median nearest-neighbor distance or how to compare them with mean nearest-neighbor distances.

---

From simulations of random Poisson process on the $n = (1,2,3)$ dimensional cube, I have found a few power law scaling relationships.  Let $f(n,x)$ be the median closest nearest-neighbor spacing for $x$ points placed randomly and uniformly in an $n$-dimensional cube:

$f(n = 1, x) \approx 0.000155908 + \frac{0.518396}{x^{1.05075}}$

$f(n = 2, x) \approx 0.00325158 + \frac{0.651363}{x^{0.555154}}$

$f(n = 3, x) \approx 0.011841 + \frac{0.763755}{x^{0.395774}}$

Comment: This site is for research level mathematics.

Comment: @Carl It's not at all clear to me that this isn't research level.  I did a literature search before asking this question, and (1) I've never seen a treatment for median nearest-neighbor distances, and (2) I've found papers looking at developing more precise descriptions for nearest-neighbor distances in three-dimensions: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0026080072900481

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @user42734.  The article you cite deals with finite sized particles constrained not to overlap, which is much harder.   For your problem the calculation is very straightforward, but I guess not more so than many other questions here.  See section 2 of Martin Haenggi. "On distances in uniformly random networks." Information Theory, IEEE Transactions on $\bf 51$ (2005): 3584-3586.  I find the prob that nearest distance is less than the mean is $1-e^{-\Gamma(1+1/d)^d}$, so the mean is greater than the median for $d\leq 3$ and otherwise less.

Comment: Sorry, that should be IEEE Transactions on Information Theory